# White space around image?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display an image, using bootstrap however I get white space on the sides of the image. This is what it looks like:

[image: Image1] [image: Image2]

And here is the Html code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
             <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.ID })">
                @if (item.Picture != null)
                {
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(item.Picture)" height="200" width="200" />
                     </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="~/Images/Silhouette.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
                    </div>
                }
                </a> <br />
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.ID })
             </div>
         }
    </div>
</div>
```

and Css:

```
html,body
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.img {
border:1px solid black;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: `.img { display: block; }` to `.img { display: inline-block; }`. Also you can put the border on the image itself.

Comment: @pol thank you works perfect, if you don't mind me asking what's the difference between the two?

Comment: `block` makes the element cover 1 row, essentially pushing everything in it's way. `inline-block` basically acts as `inline`. Read more about `display` property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the borders in the `img` tag instead.

CSS:

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.img, .img img {
    display: block;
}

.img img{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```